# Where did Stack Exchange get the idea of reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

In Daniel Suarez' books *Daemon* and *Freedom (TM)*, the Darknet (aka D-Space) is basically a network of technophiles who rate each other depending on their actions (albeit in real life), which affects their overall reputation rating. Processes are automated and decisions made by the community based on voting. The way the Stack Exchange websites work remind me of this (granted there are major differences), kind of an eerie similarity, for anyone who knows what the book is about.

Is that where Stack Exchange got the idea of an overall reputation rating based on summing the outcomes of votes for individual actions? Or from a common ancestor? Where did the idea come from?

Comment: Actually, Stack Exchange got the idea from Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've read those books, and I highly recommend them to anyone who hasn't read them.

SE got the idea for rep from Reddit, I believe. Same with the upvote and downvote ideas.  I know that the orginal vision (as it said in the faq in the early days) was that the site was a cross between reddit, wikipedia, other Q&A sites, etc.

Comment: I figured it was from slashdot.

Comment: Could be.  Slashdot predates Reddit.

Comment: @jcolebrand: Yeah, reddit got the idea for karma from Slashdot, and the general basis from Digg.

Comment: I thought Xbox Live was also an inspiration, but maybe that's just for badges.

Answer (score 1):

[**Computer games.**](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22the%20gamification%20of%20life%22)